# about Compile and return type

Tags: compile

In the mathematica document "tutorial/CompilingWolframLanguageExpressions"

**1**

It says about how to set return type of a called function you used in `Compile`.

```
Clear[com]
com[i_] := Binomial[2 i, i]

test=Compile[{x, {i, _Integer}}, x^com[i], {{com[_], _Integer}}]
```

From the above example, we can see that because the `com` function evaluates to integer, so we set `{{com[_], _Integer}}` to let `Compile` know the return type of `com`.

But if you inspect it further

```
Needs["CompiledFunctionTools`"]
CompilePrint[test]
```

You can see there is `MainEvaluate` when calling function `com`.

**So, I don't understand the meaning of this example in the document. If a compiled function has a `MainEvaluate` process, then I think compiling it is just nonsense, for it won't speed up things, right?**

**2**

Then I came up with another question, it is also mentioned in the same document page. If we compile `Sqrt` as below

```
sqrtcom1 = Compile[{{x, _Real}}, Sqrt[x]]
```

we will run into problems if we evaluate `sqrtom1[-1.]`, it will give errors like

> CompiledFunction::cfn: Numerical error encountered at instruction 1;
>   proceeding with uncompiled evaluation. >>

This is because the return type of `Sqrt` is assumed to be real by default. This can be see from

```
In[20]:= ToCompiledProcedure[sqrtcom1][[4]]

Out[20]= CompiledResult[Register[Real, 1]]
```

So, theoretically we could solve this by

```
sqrtcom2 = Compile[{{x, _Real}}, Sqrt[x], {{Sqrt[_], _Complex}}]
```

But this is not working!! `ToCompiledProcedure[sqrtcom2][[4]]` still gives `CompiledResult[Register[Real, 1]]` and `sqrtcom2` still gives errors.

Why is it not working?

Comment: I doubt the type inferencing will do anything with built-in functions. Just declare the input as `_Complex`, e.g. `In[53]:= sqrtcom1 = Compile[{{x, _Complex}}, Sqrt[x]];
sqrtcom1[-1.1]

Out[54]= 0. + 1.04880884817 I`

Comment: @DanielLichtblau I know `_Complex` works. So just as halirutan says in the link provided by Jason B. " one of the situations where the third argument of Compile is required is when your compiled code needs to make a MainEvaluate call". Can I safely change the word "one of" as "only one"? Is there any other situations?

Comment: I timed the different solutions using `RepeatedTiming` on the root of -4 and found uncompiled `Sqrt` fastest, followed by `sqrtHal` and `sqrtHal2` accepting real input, then `sqrtcom1` accepting complex input, and `sqrtcom3` involving a `MainEvaluate` call. Curiously, `sqrtHal` was slightly faster than `sqrtHal2`, but it became clear when I looked at `CompilePrint` that `sqrtHal2` involves an additional complex addition in `x + 0. I`,  which `sqrtHal` lacks.

Comment: Regarding why `sqrtcom2` doesn't work, it seems, as you may already suspect, `Compile` ignores the third argument for supported functions. Only when a function requires a `MainEvaluate` call does `Compile` look at the third argument for the function's return type. I think the answer by @JasonB supports this conjecture.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let me counter Daniel Lichtblau's answer

> This has zero to do with type inferencing.

by saying, the example in the tutorial you linked is all about type inference. It is not about compiling `com` to make it faster. It is about helping the compiler to deduce the correct type for the expression.

You have to understand one thing: Highlevel *Mathematica* language is untyped, which means that it is not known upfront whether `Sqrt[x]` is an integer, a real, a complex or whether it stays as a general expression. It all depends on the value that `x` has.

Compiled code is completely different, because all variables will have a type. Either explicitly given by you, or derived/assumed by the compiler.

Therefore, your first question is not about whether or not `com` inside the compile will be too slow. The question is, can the compiler derive the type of `com` and therefore assume a correct return type.

Since this example does work correctly even without the explicit type hint, let me give a different example. Here, `realf` is a function that returns a real number, when the input is an integer. In *Mathematica* 10.3, this leads to an error message:

```
realf[i_] := 1.5*i;
f1 = Compile[{{i, _Integer}}, realf[i]]
```

Calling `f1[3]` will give you a warning, saying that `realf` will be the reason that the uncompiled version of `f1` is used. If you check the `f1` with `CompilePrint` you will find the line

```
I1 = MainEvaluate[ Hold[realf][ I0]]
```

The important part is that `I1` means *integer register*. So because `Compile` has no information about `realf`, it assumes this call will be of type integer which is wrong. If we change the definition to

```
f2 = Compile[{{i, _Integer}}, realf[i], {{realf[_], _Real}}]
```

and check the compiled code again, we see that *now* a real register is used for the result of `realf`.

```
R0 = MainEvaluate[ Hold[realf][ I0]]
```

Therfore, `f2[3]` will run without message since the types are consistent. Nevertheless, `realf` will be an external call that is evaluated by the kernel.

What Daniel's answer is showing you is, that in the specific example of `com` being defined as `Binomial`, you can expand the call and indeed compile all instructions to gain a lot of speed.

As for your second example,

```
Compile[{{x, _Real}}, Sqrt[x]]
```

there is one additional thing to note: You call `Sqrt[x]` where `x` is the input of type `Real`. Therefore, the compiler deduces that you want the square-root that works on reals. It seems, not even the type hint at the end of `Compile` prevents this, but there is a simpler solution:

```
sqrtHal = Compile[{{x, _Real}}, 
  Module[{xx = 0. I},
   xx = x;
   Sqrt[xx]
  ]
]
```

Look what we did: we created another variable `xx` and by giving an initial complex value, we force the type-system to assume `xx` to be complex. The rest works like in most programming languages. When we assign `xx=x` a type-conversion takes place and `xx` is still complex where the imaginary part is zero and the real part is `x`. Furthermore, the correct complex `Sqrt` function is selected and therefore

```
sqrtHal[-1]
(* 0. + 1. I *)
```

works without problems.

As soon as you have understood the reasons behind this, you easily find another solution:

```
sqrtHal2 = Compile[{{x, _Real}},
  Sqrt[x + 0. I]
 ]
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I think your `sqrtHal ` is equivalent to `Compile[{{x, _Complex}}`, right?

Comment: @matheorem No, not exactly. The difference is that in my version, the input argument is a real that in one way or the other needs to be converted to a complex. In the `{x,_Complex}` definition, the input argument is a complex from the beginning. Just check the `CompilePrint` output.

Comment: And my original first question is that: We always compile for faster performance, and `MainEvaluate` surely spoil this. It seems good that Mathematica provide such a type setting functionality  for `Compile`, but it is useless. Am I missing something?

Comment: Ok, I understand the difference of `sqrtHal ` now

Comment: @matheorem Your second question: You forget that usually our algorithms have more than a few lines. Therefore, it is easily possible that you can speed up large parts of your algorithm, but there is an instruction that cannot be compiled. If the overall runtime is still much better, even if we have some `MainEvaluate` calls in it, then you would still use the compiled function, right? The problem here on stackexchange is that you somehow get a wrong view, because so many people come here and try to speed up one-liners by wrapping `Compile` around it. This of course rarely helps.

Comment: Ok, but compile a large bulk of code is so difficult, because so many top level function can't be compiled. I remember Rob Knapp said never have to compile a large bulk. Recently `Inverse` and `LinearSolve` is a big headache for me. Because, I need them in an iteration process, a single `MainEvaluate` simply makes `Compile` useless. According to http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/22622/4742, seems librarylink calling lapack is much faster than built-in `Inverse`. I don't know why, `Inverse` should be also using lapack internally

Comment: My remark was to the effect that the type of `com` was not relevant to the requirement of invoking `MainEvaluate`. Moreover I saw nothing to indicate that `Compile` was getting that particular type inference incorrect.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Yes, this is the reason I had to use a different example. Nevertheless, exactly th `com` example is used in the [compile tutorial](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/CompilingWolframLanguageExpressions.html#13931) to explain type inference.

Comment: (1) Regarding `Inverse` et al and Lapack, yes, for machine number input `Inverse` uses Lapack with BLAS underneath that. If the matrices are relatively small, the speed there might be less than preprocesing time (e.g. for basic checking that it is a square matrix, determining the matrix is machine numbers, packing  if it is not a packed array, maybe some other checks I am forgetting).

Comment: (2) If the matrix is large, however, then `LinearSolve` is likely to be both faster and (slightly) more accurate.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau You are absolutely right. I tested it this afternoon. Unfortunately, my matrix is the smallest 2x2. Do you have any suggestion on this matter?

Comment: (Back to type inferencing..) My hope is that the example is there because the inferencing is working as advertised. Were it working incorrectly I'd be inclined to suspect bad inferencing for a need to use `MainEvaluate`. But that was required for a very different reason, unrelated to type inferencing.

Comment: For a small matrix it may still save an iota to use `LinearSolve`. But also note that now you are in the sort of situation @Halirutan indicated in a comment, to the effect that `Compile` might be advantageous for the other stuff. Explicit loops can be faster when used in `Compile`, for example, since iterator variables and bonds checks are done in low level code rather than via the interpreter (the main evaluator).

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Yeah, Put `Do` in compile helps, only sightly. And I don't understand this. There are much more work to do related to exiting and entering the `MainEvaluate`, why it doesn't get slower?

Answer (score 5):

This has zero to do with type inferencing. There is no `Compile` support for `Binomial`. This variant should show the same `MainEvaluate` invocation:

```
test2 = Compile[{x, {i, _Integer}}, x^Binomial[2*i, i]]
```

Let's see if there are evaluator calls:

```
test2 // InputForm

(* Out[40]//InputForm=
CompiledFunction[{10, 10.3, 5468}, {_Real, _Integer}, 
 {{3, 0, 0}, {2, 0, 0}, {3, 0, 1}}, {{2, {2, 0, 1}}}, {0, 4, 2, 0, 0}, 
 {{15, 1, 0, 2}, {47, Binomial, 2, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 3}, 
  {41, 263, 3, 0, 0, 2, 0, 3, 3, 0, 1}, {1}}, 
 Function[{x, i}, x^Binomial[2*i, i]], Evaluate] *)
```

Same story except slightly more efficient because it is a direct call to `Binomial` rather than to `com`.
One can evade this, and get a modest speed improvement, by resorting to the `FunctionExpand` form of `Binomial`.

```
test3 = compile[{x, {i, _Integer}}, x^FunctionExpand[com[i]]] /. 
   compile -> Compile;
test3 // InputForm

(* Out[45]//InputForm=
CompiledFunction[{10, 10.3, 5468}, {_Real, _Integer}, 
 {{3, 0, 0}, {2, 0, 0}, {3, 0, 2}}, {{3.141592653589793, {3, 0, 1}}, 
  {2, {2, 0, 1}}, {1, {2, 0, 4}}, {0.5, {3, 0, 3}}}, {0, 6, 7, 0, 0}, 
 {{15, 1, 0, 2}, {41, 263, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 2, 0, 3}, 
  {40, 59, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 2}, {10, 0, 4}, {13, 3, 4, 5}, 
  {40, 76, 3, 0, 5, 3, 0, 4}, {12, 4, 0, 2}, {40, 76, 2, 0, 2, 2, 0, 5}, 
  {10, 5, 5}, {40, 60, 3, 0, 5, 3, 0, 6}, {10, 3, 5}, {16, 5, 2, 4, 6, 5}, 
  {41, 263, 3, 0, 0, 3, 0, 5, 3, 0, 2}, {1}}, 
 Function[{x, i}, x^((2^(2*i)*Gamma[1/2 + i])/(Sqrt[Pi]*Gamma[1 + i]))], 
 Evaluate] *)
```

We get modest speed gains as we proceed.

```
AbsoluteTiming[Do[test[4., 3], {10^6}]]
AbsoluteTiming[Do[test2[4., 3], {10^6}]]
AbsoluteTiming[Do[test3[4., 3], {10^6}]]

(* Out[46]= {1.410492, Null}

Out[47]= {0.904184, Null}

Out[48]= {0.513575, Null} *)
```

One might get further speedup using `Listability` and maybe parallelism.

Comment: BTW, you could use `Evaluate` for `Compile[{x, {i, _Integer}}, Evaluate[x^FunctionExpand[com[i]]]]`

Answer (score 2):

I can't pretend to fully understand this, there are others here like Leonid or Halirutan that [talked about this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/43141/9490).  I notice on [this page](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/Compile/tutorial/Operation.html) in the section about "Type Propagation" it says

> This shows that for this input, the compiler chooses the result of the
>   square root to also be a real number. This is less general but faster.

So maybe it treats `Sqrt` specially?  This is a workaround,

```
sqrt[x_] := Sqrt[x];
sqrtcom3 = Compile[{{x, _Real}},
   sqrt[x]
   , {{sqrt[_], _Complex, 0}}];
sqrtcom3[-4.]
(* 0. + 2. I *)
```

Comment: Worth mentioning this method involves a `MainEvaluate` call, which can be seen in `CompilePrint`, the OP wants to avoid.

Comment: Also, I'm curious why the complex type specification is `{sqrt[_], _Complex, 0}` instead of just `{sqrt[_],_Complex}`. Both produce equivalent answers, but I don't see any mention of a 3rd argument in the documentation. Is it supposed to specify a default value?

Comment: Ok I realized the 3rd argument of the type specification specifies the rank of the array of that type, as it does for the input type specification. Unfortunately this wasn't evident from the docs.