# Compile function - error but correct calculation

Tags: compile

I am investigating `Compile` lately and I came across the following problem.

I define a 2-variable function

```
  f[x_, y_] := 
  If[x < 0 || y < 0, 0, 
  PDF[PoissonDistribution[3], x]*PDF[PoissonDistribution[2], y]
];
```

and then I have a new function, which I intend to compile. The non-compiled version of it is:

```
g[gh_, ga_] := 
  Sum[f[i, j], {i, 1 - gh - ga, 10}, {j, 0, i - 1 + gh - ga}];
```

So when I call for `N[g[0, 0]` I get `0.584997`.

This is my attempt to compile it

```
gC = Compile[{{gh, _Integer}, {ga, _Integer}}, 
   Sum[f[i, j], {i, 1 - gh - ga, 10}, {j, 0, i - 1 + gh - ga}]
   ];
```

and when I call for  `N[gC[0, 0]` I get the very same answer (`0.584997`) along with the following error.

> CompiledFunction::cfex: Could not complete external evaluation at
>   instruction 13; proceeding with uncompiled evaluation. >>

Can anyone understand what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Look at http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1096/list-of-compilable-functions - you'll find `PDF` is not compilable.

Comment: You're against rule 1, 2, 3 [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/104031/1871).

Comment: Try `f[x_, y_] = PDF[PoissonDistribution[3], x] PDF[PoissonDistribution[2], y] // FunctionExpand` instead and report back.

Comment: @blochwavw @xzczd   I followed xzczd's methos in my  previous post here http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/108121/how-to-speed-up-calculation-of-this-equation-findroot and created the following (more naive) problem, and compile worked fine.                                        `f1[x_]:=PDF[PoissonDistribution[l],x]`                                                           `cf1 = Compile[{l}, #,RuntimeOptions -> "EvaluateSymbolically" -> False] &@Sum[f1[i], {i, 0, 2.5}];`                                                               `FindRoot[cf1@l == 0.4605263157894738, {l, 1}]`

Comment: @J.M. Unfortunately it didn't work

Comment: That may be due to you not clearing the previous definition for `f` that used `:=` instead of `=`.

Comment: Guys, I don't think this question is simple or is easily found in the documentation…

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your function is simple enough that you don't need to rely on pre-defined functions like `PDF` or `PoissonDistribution`, just code it all yourself

```
gC = Compile[{{gh, _Integer}, {ga, _Integer}}, 
   Sum[If[x >= 0 && y >= 0, 3^x/(E^3 x!) 2^y/(E^2 y!), 0], {x, 
     1 - gh - ga, 10}, {y, 0, x - 1 + gh - ga}]];

gC[0, 0]
(* 0.584997 *)
```

### Edit

As pointed out by J.M., you are safer defining the function as

```
gC = Compile[{{gh, _Integer}, {ga, _Integer}}, 
   Sum[If[x >= 0 && y >= 0, 
     Exp[x Log[3] - 3 - LogGamma[x + 1]] Exp[
       y Log[2] - 2 - LogGamma[y + 1]], 0], {x, 1 - gh - ga, 10}, {y, 
     0, x - 1 + gh - ga}]];
```

which does not give numerical errors for any of the inputs I tested.

Comment: `Factorial[]` is not compilable tho. For safety against overflow, `2^y/(E^2 y!)` should be replaced by `Exp[y Log[2] - 2 - LogGamma[y + 1]]`, and similarly for the other Poisson PDF.

Comment: @J.M. this is interesting to me, because my first reaction to your comment was that it obviously does compile in this instance.  But it appears to fail when the number is above 20:  If you define `fac = Compile[{{y, _Integer}}, y! ];` then `fac[20]` executes without fail, but `fac[21]` falls back to uncompiled evaluation.

Comment: But, if you instead define `fac = Compile[{{y, _Real}}, y!];` then the threshold is higher, `fac[170]` evaluates, but `fac[171]` falls back to the uncompiled form.

Comment: @JasonB Yes you are right. My initial goal was to use it in a similar case, where `f` was recursive. I got the very same errors I get with my initial post's error. Then I thought that it is the already discussed (in this site) issue with compile and recursive functions, but to my surprise problem occurred to a far more simple function too.

Answer (score 2):

Just wanted to provide an answer to the OP's question

> Can anyone understand what am I doing wrong?

which I feel hasn't really been addressed. The original error stems from the compiler assuming `f[i,j]` returns an integer instead of a real (when `i` and `j` are positive), because the inputs of the compiled function `gC` are integers and the type of `f[i,j]` is unspecified. To see that this is the case, `On["CompilerWarnings"]` prior to compilation and check the problematic instruction 13 of

```
Needs["CompiledFunctionTools`"];
CompilePrint@gC
```

to see

> 13 I16 = MainEvaluate[ Hold[f][ I14, I15]]

To my understanding, which may be wrong because the output of `CompilePrint` isn't documented, `CompilePrint` prefixes integer registers with `I`, so this instruction implies an integer register is being assigned the result of f. When `N[gC[0,0]]` is evaluated, `f[i,j]` is called with positive `i` and `j`, returning a real, which instruction 13 attempts to assign to an integer register. Because this instruction cannot be executed, the kernel reverts to uncompiled evaluation, which works because it makes no such assumptions on the return type of `f`.

Also, the `MainEvaluate` in instruction 13 also requires a call to the Wolfram Language evaluator, which means `f` is effectively [uncompiled](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1814/41227). This is less relevant to the OP's question because it causes a performance penalty instead of an error, which the OP was concerned about. Also, just because `f` is uncompiled doesn't mean the compiled code will definitely not be sped up, since `Sum` is still compiled. However, the accepted answer provides a way to compute the same answer while avoiding `MainEvaluate`, and should be preferentially used in production runs over other solutions.

For purely academic interest though, we may avoid the error by making sure the compiler knows the return type of `f` is real. There are [several ways to do this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/102627/about-compile-and-return-type), but I will just describe the two most direct ones. The canonical way is using the 3rd argument of `compile`

```
gC = Compile[{{gh, _Integer}, {ga, _Integer}}, 
Sum[f[i, j], {i, 1 - gh - ga, 10}, {j, 0, i - 1 + gh - ga}], 
{{_f, _Real}}];
```

The less memory efficient way is to compile with real input,

```
gC = Compile[{{gh, _Real}, {ga, _Real}}, 
Sum[f[i, j], {i, 1 - gh - ga, 10}, {j, 0, i - 1 + gh - ga}]];
```

In this case, the compiler still warns it will assume the return type of `f`. However, it correctly assumes `f` returns a real, given `gC` takes real arguments.

I should stress that these methods do not avoid the `MainEvaluate` and will not be as efficient as the accepted answer.