# Improve recursive function (memoization)

Tags: performance-tuning, recursion

These days I am trying to rewrite the following recursive function, in order to gain some speed. It is crucial because I end up using 4-5 similar functions, and I need to decrease execution time.

This is my original function

```
Clear[function]
difference = 0;
remaining = 80;


p6h = 0.0171;
p4h = 0.0171;
p2h = 0.00857;
p1h = 0.001906;

p6a = 0.02446;
p4a = 0.0244;
p2a = 0.012234;
p1a = 0.00271;

pns = 1 - p6h - p4h - p2h - p1h - p1a - p2a - p4a - p6a;


function[t_, d_] := 
  function[t, d] = 
   If[t > 80, 0, 
    If[d == difference && t == remaining, 1, 
     p6h*function[t + 1, d - 6] + p4h*function[t + 1, d - 4] + 
      p2h*function[t + 1, d - 2] + p1h*function[t + 1, d - 1] + 
      p6a*function[t + 1, d + 6] + p4a*function[t + 1, d + 4] + 
      p2a*function[t + 1, d + 2] + p1a*function[t + 1, d + 1] + 
      pns*function[t + 1, d]]];
```

Once function is defined I seek several summations similar to these (below my timings)

```
function[0, 0] // AbsoluteTiming
Sum[function[0, i], {i, 1, 560}] // AbsoluteTiming
Sum[function[0, -i], {i, 1, 560}] // AbsoluteTiming
Sum[function[0, i], {i, -560, 560}] // AbsoluteTiming

(*
{0.589095, 0.0399939}    
{0.679503, 0.293243}    
{0.710139, 0.666763}    
{0.00101605, 1.} *)
```

I searched stackexchange and found several topics discussing about dynamic programming and recursive function. I even tried to replicate some methods provided by @LeonidShifrin but either I fail, or I end up with slower evaluation times.

Based on his answer [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/24988/can-one-identify-the-design-patterns-of-mathematica/25150#25150): i wrote this

```
  functionB[t_, d_] :=
 Block[{functionB},
  functionB[t1_, d1_] := 
   functionB[t1, d1] = 
    If[t1 > 80, 0, 
     If[d1 == difference && t1 == remaining, 1, 
      p6h*functionB[t1 + 1, d1 - 6] + p4h*functionB[t1 + 1, d1 - 4] + 
       p2h*functionB[t1 + 1, d1 - 2] + p1h*functionB[t1 + 1, d1 - 1] +
        p6a*functionB[t1 + 1, d1 + 6] + 
       p4a*functionB[t1 + 1, d1 + 4] + p2a*functionB[t1 + 1, d1 + 2] +
        p1a*functionB[t1 + 1, d1 + 1] + pns*functionB[t1 + 1, d1]]];
  functionB[t, d]
  ]
```

but it is dramatically slow.

I tried this approach too

```
Clear[functionB2, "functionB2`*"]

Begin["functionB2`"];


functionB2[t1_, d1_] := 
 functionB2[t1, d1] = 
  Expand[If[t1 > 80, 0, 
    If[d1 == difference && t1 == remaining, 1, 
     p6h*functionB2[t1 + 1, d1 - 6] + p4h*functionB2[t1 + 1, d1 - 4] +
       p2h*functionB2[t1 + 1, d1 - 2] + 
      p1h*functionB2[t1 + 1, d1 - 1] + 
      p6a*functionB2[t1 + 1, d1 + 6] + 
      p4a*functionB2[t1 + 1, d1 + 4] + 
      p2a*functionB2[t1 + 1, d1 + 2] + 
      p1a*functionB2[t1 + 1, d1 + 1] + pns*functionB2[t1 + 1, d1]]]]



End[];
```

but times are slightly worse than original approach.

```
(*
{0.641918, 0.0399939}
{0.738379, 0.293243}
{0.747237, 0.666763}
{0.00101013, 1.}
*)
```

Based on a previous question [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/108121/how-to-speed-up-calculation-of-this-equation-findroot) and [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/109304/compile-function-error-but-correct-calculation) I tried to compile it, but unfortunately I found out that it is not as easy as I thought (or even possible).

Finally, I though about setting all values calculated into a table, like this

```
> s = Table[function[0, i], {i, -560, 560}];
```

in order to add table's elements accordingly, only to find out that it is actually the same thing with memoization.

Could anyone help me rewrite the original `function` in order to gain speed?

---

**update 18/3/2016**

based on this usage of `Block` suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7342748/dynamic-programming-in-mathematica-how-to-automatically-localize-and-or-clear/7345257#7345257) I again failed to improve speeds. I actually made it terribly slow once again

```
Clear[function]
difference = 0;
remaining = 80;
p6h = 0.0171;
p4h = 0.0171;
p2h = 0.00857;
p1h = 0.001906;
p6a = 0.02446;
p4a = 0.0244;
p2a = 0.012234;
p1a = 0.00271;
pns = 1 - p6h - p4h - p2h - p1h - p1a - p2a - p4a - p6a;

ClearAll[defWrap];
SetAttributes[defWrap, HoldFirst];
defWrap[fcall_] := Block[{function},
   function[t_, d_] := 
    function[t, d] = 
     If[t > 80, 0, 
      If[d == difference && t == remaining, 1, 
       p6h*function[t + 1, d - 6] + p4h*function[t + 1, d - 4] + 
        p2h*function[t + 1, d - 2] + p1h*function[t + 1, d - 1] + 
        p6a*function[t + 1, d + 6] + p4a*function[t + 1, d + 4] + 
        p2a*function[t + 1, d + 2] + p1a*function[t + 1, d + 1] + 
        pns*function[t + 1, d]]];
   fcall];

ClearAll[function];
function[tt_, kk_] := defWrap[function[tt, kk]];

Sum[function[0, i], {i, 1, 10}] // AbsoluteTiming
(* {6.28821, 0.197245} *)
```