# Numerical Error using compile

Tags: performance-tuning, numerics, mathematical-optimization, compile, numerical-value

I'm trying to compile a function and I'm running into the following error

> CompiledFunction::cfne :  Numerical error encountered; proceeding with uncompiled evaluation.

I think I have succeeded in isolating the part of the code causing this issue. I'm pasting the code below. The issue is arising from `auxphix`. I have commented out the part causing the issue so now it runs without raising any issues, but its obviously the wrong answer.

```
(*Defining parameter values*)


SKRMin = 10.;
RepRate = 500000000.;
mu3 = 2.000000000000000 10^-04;
Y0 = 6.007379741251949 10^-07;
eps = 1.000000000000000 10^-25;
betasec = 57.564627324851145;
ed = 0.01;
fEC = 1.16;
Nb = 10^11.;
RateMin = SKRMin/RepRate;
NdBpoints = 200; 
dBmin = 0.; 
dBmax = 65.;
step = 0.01;
index = 0;
bitsDecoy = 2.;
bitsBasis = 2.;
stepBasis = 0.5^bitsBasis;
stepDecoy = 0.5^bitsDecoy;






(*Main function*)

keyrateFuncBetter = 
 Compile[{dB, qx, pmu1, pmu2, mu1, mu2}, 
  Module[{SKRMin = 10., RepRate = 500. 10^6., mu3 = 2. 10^-04, 
    Y0 = 6.00738 10^-07, eps = 1. 10^-25., betasec = 57.5646, 
    ed = 0.01, fEC = 1.16, Nb = 10^11., RateMin = SKRMin/RepRate, 
    NdBpoints = 200., dBmin = 0., dBmax = 65., step = 0.01, 
    index = 0., bitsDecoy = 2., bitsBasis = 2., 
    stepBasis = 0.5^bitsBasis, stepDecoy = 0.5^bitsDecoy, pmu3, 
    etasys, nxmu1, nxmu2, nxmu3, Emu1, Emu2, Emu3, mxmu1, mxmu2, 
    mxmu3, nzmu1, nzmu2, nzmu3, mzmu1, mzmu2, mzmu3, nx, mx, nz, mz, 
    eobs, tao0, nxmu3m, nxmu2p, auxSx0, Sx0, Sx0true, tao1, nxmu2m, 
    nxmu3p, nxmu1p, auxSx1, Sx1, Sx1true, nzmu3m, nzmu2p, auxSz0, Sz0,
     Sz0true, nzmu2m, nzmu3p, nzmu1p, auxSz1, Sz1, Sz1true, mzmu2p, 
    mzmu3m, auxVz1, Vz1, nzmu1singleerror, nzmu2singleerror, 
    nzmu3singleerror, nzsingleerror, VzbySz, aux1, aux2, auxphix, 
    phix, lambdaEC, keylength, keyrate},
   
   pmu3 = 1. - pmu1 - pmu2;
   etasys = 10.^(-dB/10.);
   
   nxmu1 = Floor[Nb*qx*qx*pmu1*(1. - (1. - Y0)*Exp[-etasys*mu1])]; 
   nxmu2 = Floor[Nb*qx*qx*pmu2*(1. - (1. - Y0)*Exp[-etasys*mu2])]; 
   nxmu3 = Floor[Nb*qx*qx*pmu3*(1. - (1. - Y0)*Exp[-etasys*mu3])];
   
   Emu1 = ((Y0/2. - ed)*Exp[-etasys*mu1] + 
       ed)/(1. - (1. - Y0)*Exp[-etasys*mu1]); 
   Emu2 = ((Y0/2. - ed)*Exp[-etasys*mu2] + 
       ed)/(1. - (1. - Y0)*Exp[-etasys*mu2]); 
   Emu3 = ((Y0/2. - ed)*Exp[-etasys*mu3] + 
       ed)/(1. - (1. - Y0)*Exp[-etasys*mu3]); 
   mxmu1 = Ceiling[nxmu1*Emu1]; mxmu2 = Ceiling[nxmu2*Emu2]; 
   mxmu3 = Ceiling[nxmu3*Emu3];
   
   nzmu1 = 
    Floor[Nb*(1. - qx)*(1. - qx)*
      pmu1*(1. - (1. - Y0)*Exp[-etasys*mu1])]; 
   nzmu2 = Floor[
     Nb*(1. - qx)*(1. - qx)*pmu2*(1. - (1. - Y0)*Exp[-etasys*mu2])]; 
   nzmu3 = Floor[
     Nb*(1. - qx)*(1. - qx)*pmu3*(1. - (1. - Y0)*Exp[-etasys*mu3])];
   
   Emu1 = ((Y0/2. - ed)*Exp[-etasys*mu1] + 
       ed)/(1. - (1. - Y0)*Exp[-etasys*mu1]);
   Emu2 = ((Y0/2. - ed)*Exp[-etasys*mu2] + 
       ed)/(1. - (1. - Y0)*Exp[-etasys*mu2]);
   Emu3 = ((Y0/2. - ed)*Exp[-etasys*mu3] + 
       ed)/(1. - (1. - Y0)*Exp[-etasys*mu3]);
   mzmu1 = Ceiling[nzmu1*Emu1];
   mzmu2 = Ceiling[nzmu2*Emu2];
   mzmu3 = Ceiling[nzmu3*Emu3];
   
   nx = nxmu1 + nxmu2 + nxmu3;
   mx = mxmu1 + mxmu2 + mxmu3;
   nz = nzmu1 + nzmu2 + nzmu3;
   mz = mzmu1 + mzmu2 + mzmu3;
   eobs = If[nx == 0., 0., mx/nx];
   
   tao0 = pmu1*Exp[-mu1] + pmu2*Exp[-mu2] + pmu3*Exp[-mu3];
   nxmu3m = (Exp[mu3]/
       pmu3)*(nxmu3/(1. + (3.*betasec + 
            Sqrt[8.*betasec*nxmu3 + betasec^2.])/(2.*(nxmu3 - 
              betasec))));
   nxmu2p = (Exp[mu2]/
       pmu2)*(nxmu2/(1. - (-betasec + 
            Sqrt[8.*betasec*nxmu2 + 9.*betasec^2.])/(2.*(nxmu2 + 
              betasec))));
   
   auxSx0 = tao0*(mu2*nxmu3m - mu3*nxmu2p)/(mu2 - mu3);
   
   Sx0 = If[auxSx0 > 0., auxSx0, 0.];
   
   (*Sx0true=Nb*qx^2*tao0*Y0;*)
   tao1 = pmu1*Exp[-mu1]*mu1 + pmu2*Exp[-mu2]*mu2 + pmu3*Exp[-mu3]*mu3;
   nxmu2m = (Exp[mu2]/
       pmu2)*(nxmu2/(1. + (3.*betasec + 
            Sqrt[8.*betasec*nxmu2 + betasec^2.])/(2.*(nxmu2 - 
              betasec))));
   nxmu3p = (Exp[mu3]/
       pmu3)*(nxmu3/(1. - (-betasec + 
            Sqrt[8.*betasec*nxmu3 + 9.*betasec^2.])/(2.*(nxmu3 + 
              betasec))));
   nxmu1p = (Exp[mu1]/
       pmu1)*(nxmu1/(1. - (-betasec + 
            Sqrt[8.*betasec*nxmu1 + 9.*betasec^2.])/(2.*(nxmu1 + 
              betasec))));
   
   auxSx1 = (tao1*
       mu1*(nxmu2m - 
         nxmu3p - ((mu2^2 - mu3^2)/(mu1^2))*(nxmu1p - (Sx0/
              tao0))))/(mu1*(mu2 - mu3) - mu2^2 + mu3^2);
   
   Sx1 = If[auxSx1 > 0., auxSx1, 0.];
   
   (*Sx1true=Nb*qx^2*tao1*(1.-(1.-Y0)*(1.-etasys));*)
   nzmu3m = (Exp[mu3]/
       pmu3)*(nzmu3/(1. + (3.*betasec + 
            Sqrt[8.*betasec*nzmu3 + betasec^2])/(2*(nzmu3 - 
              betasec))));
   nzmu2p = (Exp[mu2]/
       pmu2)*(nzmu2/(1. - (-betasec + 
            Sqrt[8.*betasec*nzmu2 + 9.*betasec^2])/(2*(nzmu2 + 
              betasec))));
   
   auxSz0 = tao0*(mu2*nzmu3m - mu3*nzmu2p)/(mu2 - mu3);
   
   Sz0 = If[auxSz0 > 0., auxSz0, 0.];
   (*Sz0true=Nb*(1.-qx)^2.*tao0*Y0;*)
   
   
   
   nzmu2m = (Exp[mu2]/
       pmu2)*(nzmu2/(1. + (3.*betasec + 
            Sqrt[8.*betasec*nzmu2 + betasec^2.])/(2.*(nzmu2 - 
              betasec))));
   nzmu3p = (Exp[mu3]/
       pmu3)*(nzmu3/(1. - (-betasec + 
            Sqrt[8.*betasec*nzmu3 + 9.*betasec^2.])/(2.*(nzmu3 + 
              betasec))));
   nzmu1p = (Exp[mu1]/
       pmu1)*(nzmu1/(1. - (-betasec + 
            Sqrt[8.*betasec*nzmu1 + 9.*betasec^2.])/(2.*(nzmu1 + 
              betasec))));
   
   auxSz1 = (tao1*
       mu1*(nzmu2m - 
         nzmu3p - ((mu2^2. - mu3^2)/(mu1^2.))*(nzmu1p - (Sz0/
              tao0))))/(mu1*(mu2 - mu3) - mu2^2. + mu3^2.);
   
   Sz1 = If[auxSz1 > 0., auxSz1, 0.];
   (*Sz1true=Nb*(1.-qx)^2.*tao1*(1.-(1.-Y0)*(1.-etasys));*)
   
   
   mzmu2p = (Exp[mu2]/
       pmu2)*(mzmu2/(1. - (-betasec + 
            Sqrt[8.*betasec*mzmu2 + 9.*betasec^2.])/(2.*(mzmu2 + 
              betasec))));
   mzmu3m = (Exp[mu3]/
       pmu3)*(mzmu3/(1. + (3.*betasec + 
            Sqrt[8.*betasec*mzmu3 + betasec^2.])/(2.*(mzmu3 - 
              betasec))));
   
   auxVz1 = tao1*(mzmu2p - mzmu3m)/(mu2 - mu3);
   Vz1 = If[auxVz1 > 0., auxVz1, 0.];
   
   nzmu1singleerror = 
    Ceiling[Nb*(1. - qx)*(1. - qx)*Exp[-mu1]*
      mu1*((Y0/2. - ed)*(1. - etasys) + ed)];
   nzmu2singleerror = 
    Ceiling[Nb*(1. - qx)*(1. - qx)*Exp[-mu2]*
      mu2*((Y0/2. - ed)*(1. - etasys) + ed)];
   nzmu3singleerror = 
    Ceiling[Nb*(1. - qx)*(1. - qx)*Exp[-mu3]*
      mu3*((Y0/2. - ed)*(1. - etasys) + ed)];
   
   nzsingleerror = 
    nzmu1singleerror + nzmu2singleerror + nzmu3singleerror;
   





 (*--------------------------------------------------*)
   (*What I believe is causing the issue*)
   auxphix = If[Sz1 == 0., 0.,
     If[Sx1 == 0., Vz1/Sz1 + 0. I,
      (*aux1=((Sz1+Sx1)*(1.-Vz1/Sz1)*Vz1/Sz1)/(Sz1*Sx1*Log[2.]);
      aux2=Log[2.,((Sz1+Sx1)/(Sz1*Sx1*(1.-Vz1/Sz1)*Vz1/Sz1))*(21.^2./
      eps^2.)];*)Vz1/Sz1(*+Sqrt[aux1*aux2]*)+ 0. I]];
   (*--------------------------------------------------*) 
   






   
   phix = If[Re[auxphix] < 0.5 && Im[auxphix] == 0., Re[auxphix], 0.5];
   
    lambdaEC = fEC*If[0. < eobs < 1.,
      -eobs*Log[2., eobs] - (1. - eobs) Log[2., 1. - eobs], 0.
      ];
   
   keylength = Floor[Max[0., Sx0 + Sx1 - Sx1*If[0. < phix < 1.,
         -phix*Log[2., phix] - (1. - phix) Log[2., 1. - phix], 0.
         ] - nx*lambdaEC - Log[1./(2.*eps^4.)]]];
   
   keyrate = keylength/Nb], RuntimeOptions -> "Quality", 
  CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, 
  Parallelization -> True]




(*Output results*)
stepmul = 
  5;(*The higher the value, the faster the code runs;Ideally should \
be equal to 1*)
keytab = 
   ParallelTable[(*Quiet[*)
    Max[Table[
      keyrateFuncBetter[dB, qx, pmu1, pmu2, mu1, mu2], {mu1, 0.4, 1., 
       stepmul step}, {mu2, mu3 + 0.001, Min[0.3, mu1 - mu3 - 0.001], 
       stepmul step}, {pmu1, 0.25, 1. - 2.*stepDecoy, 
       stepDecoy}, {pmu2, stepDecoy, Min[1. - pmu1 - stepDecoy, 0.5], 
       stepDecoy}, {qx, 0.5, 1. - stepBasis, 
       stepBasis}]](*]*)(*]*), {dB, dBmin, 
     65., (dBmax - dBmin)/(NdBpoints - 1.)}]; // AbsoluteTiming

ListLogPlot[keytab]
```

If we comment out `aux1`, `aux2` and `Sqrt[aux1*aux2]` the compiled code runs with no issues. I'm not sure what the problem is with evaluating those value. The `If` statements in `auxphix` should make sure that they don't blow up to infinities.

Ultimately what I want is a very efficient code to compute `keyrateFuncBetter`. I read compiling it should help, hence why I'm here. If theres any other small tweaks that could help the efficiency of this code, its much appreciated.

EDIT

As @Domen suggested, adding `+ 0. I` in `Sqrt` and `Log` gets rid of the numerical error. However the results are not very precise in the extreme cases; when the variable `dB` gets high.

Heres the resulting plot when `stepmul` is set to `1`, the x axis corresponds to the variable `dB` and y axis is the compiled function output.

[image]

Comment: There are (at least) two main problems: **(1)** I see you have already seen a hint by [@halirutan](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/102640/75628) about adding `+ 0.I` wherever you expect negative numbers. However, you have to add it _inside_ the square root, namely `Sqrt[aux1*aux2 + 0. I]`. The same thing can also happen for logarithms, so you need `Log[2., ((Sz1 + Sx1)/(Sz1*Sx1*(1. - Vz1/Sz1)*Vz1/Sz1))*(21.^2./eps^2.) + 0. I]`. **(2)** You do not check for `Sz1 == 0` and `Sx1 == 0` (soon enough). They can be zero, which causes calculation of `aux1` or `aux2` to fail.

Comment: (1) As per your suggestion I have added `+0. I` inside the square root and Log. The code does not raise the numerical error now, however the results are not correct for low values of `Sz1` and `Sx1`. (2) I didnt understand your second point. `aux1` and `aux2` are only calculated after I check `Sz1==0` and `Sx1==0`